# Cakephp routing controller alias

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-routing

I'm trying to do the same as this site, stackoverflow, do with their URLs.

CakePHP works like this: website/controller/action/

I want to config routing to achieve this:

myWebSite.com/questions/(question_id)/**(question)**/

**eg**: myWebSite.com/questions/12874722/**cakephp-routing-controller-alias /**

I didnt figured it out how to do this bold part of URL.

Comment: What does this have to do with "_controller aliases_"? The bold part is the slugged question title. And what exactly is the actual problem? Have you read [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Notice that SO actually ignores the question title and you can put [whatever you like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466567/this-is-a-silly-url) in there, but it will redirect if you get it wrong (it's the question ID that is important)

Comment: The actual problem is that i don't know how to put it there, the question title in URL.

Comment: There are sluggable behaviour check them, also save the slug to your database to redirect user to proper url just like S.O. as mentioned by @DavidG

Comment: @DavidG A common pattern among websites. Redirect on `(SLUG != URI_SEGMENT[N])`

Comment: @self Indeed, one I've used myself too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/questions/*', array('controller' => 'questions', 'action' => 'view'));
```

In Controller/QuestionsController.php

view action get question id as

```
public function view() {
    $question_id = isset($this->request->params['pass'][0]) ? $this->request->params['pass'][0] : "";
    $question = isset($this->request->params['pass'][1]) ? $this->request->params['pass'][1] : "";

    if( empty($question_id) ) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Could not find that question');
    }

    // if $question is empty then get slug from database and redirect to /question_id/question


    // Get question details and set
}
```